# Why is FFT giving erroneous data after substracting the mean from my signal

Tags: fft, filters

I am a beginner so please excuse some of my ignorance, I am still very much learning.

My original signal comes from a DC sensor that was measuring the distance of a pulsating object. The sensor was on top of a vibrating machine. I am trying to find the frequency of the vibration of the machine and the pulsating object.

I want to know the frequencies and then I want to reduce the noise by filtering both.

Towards that end: I imported the data in GNU Octave and performed FFT. I noticed a large spike at 0Hz. Upon further reading I found that this can be due to "DC offset bias."

I subtracted the mean of my measurement to remove this bias. Now when I perform FFT I get nonsense.

[image]

GNU Octave Code:

```
DATA = file(8:end,2)

DATA_minus_avg = DATA.-mean(DATA)

subplot(4,1,1)
plot(DATA)
title('Original Data')
subplot(4,1,2)

plot(fft(DATA))
title('FFT of Original Data')
subplot(4,1,3)

plot(DATA_minus_avg)
title('Original Data minus Average')
subplot(4,1,4)

plot(fft(DATA_minus_avg))
title('FFT of Original Data minus Average')
```

The original data:

```
267.24
267.66
267.27
267.27
267.29
267.3
269.47
267.29
267.35
268.42
267.32
268.1
267.42
267.31
267.34
267.68
267.32
267.35
268.74
267.68
267.82
267.32
268.23
268.77
267.33
267.33
267.32
267.35
267.35
267.33
268.77
267.7
267.33
267.65
264.64
267.43
267.34
268.35
267.74
267.33
267.38
267.34
268.05
267.32
268.03
268.43
267.33
268.8
267.35
267.33
268.4
267.62
268.51
267.33
268.09
270.26
267.32
268.25
267.35
267.88
267.33
267.33
267.85
267.35
269.43
267.35
269.5
269.1
267.99
268.77
267.35
268.8
268.79
267.34
268.71
267.34
268.8
268.76
267.36
268.44
267.33
268.13
267.66
268.78
268.02
267.36
268.31
267.35
268.45
268.38
267.71
268.78
268.01
269.13
267.31
266.32
268.5
267.32
269.32
267.35
268.46
268.04
266.59
268.45
267.48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the Fourier transform is complex. You are likely wanting to plot the *magnitude* of the transform, which can be found by instead plotting `abs(fft(DATA))`. Similarly, if you are interested in the *phase* information of the transform, that can be found with `angle(fft(DATA))` (in MATLAB, at least).

Also, be aware that `fft` will output a spectrum beginning at 0 Hz and going to $f_s/2$ (where $f_s$ is the sample rate of the data) and back to almost 0 Hz through negative frequencies. To adjust for this, further adjust your code to `abs(fftshift(fft(DATA)))` and your associated frequencies will be `f = ((N/2):((N-1)/2))*fs/N` for an even input data and `f = (((N-1)/2):((N-1)/2))*fs/N` for an odd input data length.